# Implementing a "nag" counter for javascript cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

First and foremost, hello everyone. I know that I am new, and I apologize for the fact that I have no prior contributions.

That said, I am a student at Rasmussen. I have an assignment in my JavaScript class that requires that I create a "nag" counter that will alert the user on their fifth visit that they should register. Then I must do this for every fifth visit until the user A) Gets annoyed and stops using my website, or B) they register. At that time, I have to delete the cookie that holds the counter and the "nag" and replace it with a landing page that welcomes the user back to the website, displaying their registration credentials.

I know that this can be done, I have seen it numerous time. The problem that I am having is the fact that I am so new to JavaScript that feel like I am in way over my head. I have spent about 2 hours combing through my textbook, as well as Google, and I have not found any answers. I have asked my Instructor and fellow students for help but have yet to receive any. Te last time my instructor advised me, she said "Try Googling it."

I do not even know where to begin this assignment. I appreciate any help you may or may not be able to offer. I am not looking for a handout, or for anyone to do my assignment for me. I assure you I am in fact trying to learn something, but I feel this assignment it too much.

Comment: Sooo, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Remove all of the editorializing / meta content. Just ask your question. But before that, make an effort at doing it yourself and, if you get stuck, ask a question about *that*, showing what you've done.

Comment: some hints....on page load see if ccokie exists, if it does convert value from string to number... test it and do what's necessary...not difficult. Up to you from there, we're not here to do your homework

Comment: Okay, this was a last resort. I appreciate the advice, limited as it may be, and will try some more on my own and will hopefully be back with something to show. 

Char, what might not be hard to you, may be hard for others. Thank you for the advice though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user loads the page, read the cookie to see if it exist. If it doesn't, set count = 1.
Once a user fills in the text boxes and clicks the register button, delete the nag counter cookie and replace it with cookies containing the user's name and e-mail address.
If they don't register, the next time they load the page, set count = 2.
On every 3rd visit, implement the nag. (use logic/control flow statements to achieve this)

Comment: I am not sure how to do any of the things that you suggested, but I do appreciate the instruction. Thank you :)